# PyGObject with GStreamer examples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gstreamer, pygobject

I'd like to see some examples that uses PyGObject and GStreamer, but I could not find anything on web.

The only information available in the official website is the link to the source code for the Python binding: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html

As you can see in the page on the link above:

> GStreamer python overrides for the gobject-introspection-based pygst bindings.

PyGObject is used, but the examples on the web are out dated and could not convert them to use it.

I'd like also to ask about the documentation, there is any documentation for the Python binding of GStreamer?

Thanks.

Comment: In the most recent gtk4 blog entry, Mathias mention some improvements coming; hopefully he'll also have working pygobject examples. That was related to multimedia stuff such as video streaming, not solely gstreamer alone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good way to turn up examples using the introspected bindings offered by pygobject 3 (in contrast to the "old" static bindings offered by pygobject 2 and pygtk) is to use "gi.repository" as a search keyword.
For example, searching for "gi.repository gst" quickly leads to [a simple media player](http://lzone.de/Media%20Player%20with%20GStreamer%20and%20PyGI) and the [examples listed in the Novacut porting guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0#Python_Porting_Guide), amongst other goodies.

On documentation, best to follow the C API reference and/or consult the relevant .gir files. API references for other languages able to use introspected binding are generally not yet available, although tools to create them from the intermediate .gir files created by gobject-introspection's g-ir-scanner are being worked on.

Comment: For those coming along this topic, somebody started generating pygi api docs on https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/

Comment: @dieterv Thanks so much for adding a link to the document generator!